# how to fit a von mises distribution to my data for generating random samples

Tags: r, distribution, resampling

My data is comprised of 16 pairs of distance and bearings from a particular location.
I am  trying to generate 1000 resamples of those 16 pairs (i.e. create new sets of X2 and Y2). So that in the end I will have 1000, 16 pairs of distances and bearings resulting in new 16 spatial points.

[my data, using the bearing and the distance to generate X2 and Y2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvTRh.png)

What I have done so far is resample (reshuffle) from the 16 values I already have, but that was no go with my advisors.

```
f2 <- function(x) data.frame(bearing = sample(min(HRlog$beartoenc):max(HRlog$beartoenc), 16, replace = TRUE), 
                                distance = sample(min(HRlog$distoenc):max(HRlog$distoenc), 16, replace = TRUE))
    
    se1randcent <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq(1000), f2))
```

I have been told I should resample according to the von mises distribution, i.e fit the distribution to my data then regenerate the 16 pairs from this distribution according the K value I get.
I don't really know what this means. Can anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `circular` in R could be helpful. The von Mises distribution `kappa` parameter can be calculated from the angles you provided either using a minimization method, as I show below, or through built in maximum likelihood estimators `mle.vonmises()`. Once you have the parameters you can use `rvonmises` with the number of samples and calculated parameters to generate the sample. The generated sample seems to be on [0,2pi], so there could be some adjustment to make sure the mean values are correctly represented.

Fitting the distance would probably be a separate distribution and the issue of the possible dependency between the two is not addressed in this answer.

```
library(circular) # circular statistics and bessel functions

# converting the bearing to be on the interval [-pi,pi] which is conventional for von Mises
bearing <- c(19.07,71.88,17.23,202.39,173.67,357.04,5.82,5.82,95.53,5.82,94.13,157.67,19.07,202.39,173.67,128.15)
bearing_rad <- bearing*2*pi/360 - pi

# sample statistics
circ_mean <-  mean.circular(bearing_rad) # mu of von Mises
circ_sd <- sd.circular(bearing_rad) # related to kappa of von Mises
circ_var <- var.circular(bearing_rad)

# function to return difference in variances between
diff_vars2 <- function(kappa){
  
  # squaring to make the function convex
  return((1 - A1(kappa) - circ_var)^2)
}

# solving for kappa by matching the variances
kappa_solution <- optim(par = 1,fn=diff_vars2,lower = 0,method="L-BFGS-B")

# sample from von mises distribution
sampled_vals <- rvonmises(n=100, mu=circ_mean, kappa=kappa_solution$par)
```

### Added content based on comments

One problem with tests for uniformity are that you have a small sample size. Two methods that seem appropriate are the Rayleigh and Kuiper Tests, which test against uniformity. Background on those are given at [NCSS Manual](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Circular_Data_Analysis.pdf)

Both are implemented in `circular`, but I am not sure if the modified Rayleigh is used. The results for `bearings_rad` indicate that Rayleigh p-value = 0.2 and Kuiper p-value < 0.05.

```
rayleigh.test(x=bearing_rad)
kuiper.test(x=bearing_rad)
```

You can add the fitted histogram to the above plot by using `dvonmises`. This will give the radius, which can be converted to x and y using the standard polar coordinate translation. Making the angles work can be a bit tricky. If you don't want the rose diagram in the background you can use `plot`.

```
rose.diag(bearing_rad)

density_vals <- dvonmises(x=seq(0,2*pi,0.01)-circ_mean,mu = 0,kappa=kappa_solution$par)

x_from_polar <- density_vals*cos(seq(0,2*pi,0.01))
y_from_polar <- density_vals*sin(seq(0,2*pi,0.01))
lines(x=x_from_polar,y=y_from_polar,col='red')
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helps very much!! I have a questions, hope that's ok. If I understand correctly the von mises is generally working with angles and bearing? Or is it possible to do the same code for the distances? If I want to run it for the distances, I just switch out the "bearing_rad" to my distances? and then to generate my pairs I sample from both separately using rvonmises??

Comment: Yes, von Mises is generally applied to angles or bearings. I assume your distances are not bounded in the same way. Distances could be scaled to the range for angles, but it is probably not ideal. A rough histogram shows positively skewed distances, which suggests gamma or lognormal distribution or Box-Cox transforming it to normality. Then you can sample angles and distances to make pairs. Note that if there is dependency in the two, a copula function would be required. Testing for dependency in angle-distance data is beyond my knowledge and could be asked on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If the answer was sufficient please accept it as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi again Calvin. I have another question about the circular package and am really hoping you could help me. Is there a way with the function circular and the kappa and mu I have to produce a circular diagram like a rose diagram to represent the distribution of my angles? and also a p-value of the directionality?

Comment: When you say the p-value for directionality, what do you mean exactly? p-value for the distribution not being uniform? Sorry, it is probably clear to you but I don't use directional data much.

Comment: Yes I mean the z-value or p-value for the distribution being different from uniform. Ill try posting another question on it. I also need to visualize it in a rose diagram or something of this sort

Comment: I added to the original answer. I hope that answers your questions.